# pthread_kill IOS Crash

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

We're currently trying to make an educational virtual reality application. The only problem we're facing is to get the app running on IOS (we built it in unity). The android version works fine and has no errors. An IOS build is a must for us so we really need it working.

Underneath I have pasted a crash log from my Iphone 4s. To be honest, we have no clue what to make of it for this is our first application build.

Has anyone got any tips for us or experience in unity to IOS builds and reading a crash log? We would love to hear some! Thanks in advance.

*Edit

Unity version 5.3.4f1 Personal

Used plug-ins/SDK:
Google VR SDK for Unity
https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/

NoTouchGUI plugin
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/26494

That's it, thanks programmer for reminding me!

```html
Incident Identifier: 3A8A3253-337B-46BD-A17F-DB2B74018814
CrashReporter Key:   47190c7f1e7f3a7e344624632391e43b74cc341f
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             1666 [12315]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/65C0D573-063E-4560-9C7E-CC3250CC188B/1666.app/1666
Identifier:          com.scheurbuik.1666
Version:             0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-06-06 15:34:33.33 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-06-06 15:34:23.23 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  3

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x25616920 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x02c7230a 0x2c62000 + 66314
2   GPUToolsCore                   0x02ccbbd8 0x2cba000 + 72664
3   dyld                           0x1ff0340c ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 184
4   dyld                           0x1ff0350c ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 20
5   dyld                           0x1feffa56 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 382
6   dyld                           0x1fefeb7a ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 110
7   dyld                           0x1fefec00 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 52
8   dyld                           0x1fef2c7a dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 134
9   dyld                           0x1fef6c92 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3770
10  dyld                           0x1fef21ee dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 342
11  dyld                           0x1fef2040 _dyld_start + 64

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2562b864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d1b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d1718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2562b864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d1b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d1718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2562ac5c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d4732 pthread_kill + 62
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x255bf0ac abort + 108
3   GPUToolsCore                   0x02cbf93e 0x2cba000 + 22846
4   GPUToolsCore                   0x02cbe42e 0x2cba000 + 17454
5   GPUToolsCore                   0x02ccbaaa 0x2cba000 + 72362
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d385a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d37ce _pthread_start + 110
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x256d1724 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2562c2f8 kevent_qos + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x02c74470 0x2c62000 + 74864
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x02c6583e 0x2c62000 + 14398

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x1f185000      r6: 0xffffffff      r7: 0x1f184e84
    r8: 0x02cfe114    r9: 0x3c191908     r10: 0x029f9ccb     r11: 0x16680b30
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x1f184e78      lr: 0x256d4733      pc: 0x2562ac5c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Comment: When posting a crash log, you post your unity full version number and name of all the plugins you are using if there is one.

Comment: Update:  I've been able to test the app on an Iphone 6s today, it didn't crash and worked smoother than we could've imagine. So I think it's a memory/cpu usage crash. I have the opportunity to test the app on a iphone 5/5s tomorrow so I'll let you guys know something then.